# Error in for loop using jinja format in html5 file

Tags: python, html, django

I want to display a series of dynamic entries on my webpage.So i have used a for loop in my html5 file using jinja but keep getting this error.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 264: 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: D:\anacondapython3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 534
Python Executable:  D:\anacondapython3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['E:\\coding\\fyp\\travel',
 'D:\\anacondapython3\\python37.zip',
 'D:\\anacondapython3\\DLLs',
 'D:\\anacondapython3\\lib',
 'D:\\anacondapython3',
 'D:\\anacondapython3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'D:\\anacondapython3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'D:\\anacondapython3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'D:\\anacondapython3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Thu, 26 Mar 2020 12:29:39 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template E:\coding\fyp\travel\templates\index.html, error at line 264

Invalid block tag on line 264: 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
254                             <div class="destination_image">
255                                 <img src="images/destination_1.jpg" alt="">
256                                 <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
257                             </div>
258                             <div class="destination_content">
259                                 <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">{{dest.name}}</a></div>
260                                 <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{dest.dest}}</p></div>
261                                 <div class="destination_price">{{dest.price}}</div>
262                             </div>
263                         </div>
264                         {% endfor %}
265 
266 
267 
268                     </div>
269                 </div>
270             </div>
271         </div>
272     </div>
273 
274     <!-- Testimonials -->
```

the part i want to make dynamic using for loops look like this:

```
<!-- Destinations -->

    <div class="destinations" id="destinations">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <div class="section_subtitle">simply amazing places</div>
                    <div class="section_title"><h2>Popular Destinations</h2></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row destinations_row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="destinations_container item_grid">

                        <!-- Destination -->
                        {% for dest in dests % }
                        <div class="destination item">
                            <div class="destination_image">
                                <img src="images/destination_1.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="destination_content">
                                <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">{{dest.name}}</a></div>
                                <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{dest.dest}}</p></div>
                                <div class="destination_price">{{dest.price}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

my views.py:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Destination
# Create your views here.
def cities(request):
    dest1=Destination()
    dest1.name='california'
    dest1.dest='the city that never sleeps'
    dest1.price=750
    dest2=Destination()
    dest2.name='LA'
    dest2.dest='the peaceful city'
    dest2.price=800
    dest3=Destination()
    dest3.name='washington'
    dest3.dest='the operating city'
    dest3.price=650
    dests=[dest1,dest2,dest3]
    return render(request,'index.html',{'dests':dests})
```

my models.py:-

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Destination:
    id:int
    name:str
    img:str
    dest:str
    price:int
```

*ignore*
lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

Comment: You have a typo in the for loop tag: `{% for dest in dests % }` → `{% for dest in dests %}` without space between `%` and `}`

Answer (score 0):

on this line

```
{% for dest in dests % }
```

you have a space `% }`
remove the space